# Import in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

How  i can import 170mb Excel File with asp.net, i already write code for importing 
ExcelFile, using this code i can import small Size Excel files such as 20Mb.

i want to import Large File

Please Help Me

Thanks in Advance

Comment: what you mean to import Excel file? You want to upload it to server. Or you want make something with excel file situated on server?

Comment: What is you current code and what kind of errors are you getting?

Answer (score 3):

You need to [increase the maximum allowed upload file size](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/08/large-file-uploads-in-asp-net.aspx).

Comment: +1 Or teach your client to use FTP for such large files and then let them select a file from a folder listing via asp.net